# Input keys with values in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have problems with filling in array that has generated the key with the value from the database. Database returns 2 rows, first row should be the key and second is value for that key.

This is my code:

```
$days = array();

if($query=db::query("select dayname(date_earned) as dayEarned, sum(downloads) as dayDownloaded
from perf_earnings
where date_earned between DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND curdate()
group by dayEarned"))
    {
    while($row=$q->fetch_assoc()){
       $day = $row["dayEarned"];
       $dowSum = $row["dayDownloaded"];
       $days[$day] = $dowSum;
    }
}
```

I'm getting a empty array.

What i want to get is:

```
array(
[Monday]=>230,
[Tuesday]=>500,
[Wednesday]=>340,
etc.
)
```

WELL, as always, there was a stupid mistake whan you dont read carefully. I did not enter the $query right whan i wanted to do fetch_assoc.

I writed "$q" instead "$query".

Thanks anyway.

Comment: first execute the query manually and check

Comment: Did you bother checking if your query actually succeeded? You simply ASSUME that `$query` will be a result handle and can be run through the fetch_assoc loop. There's exactly **ONE** way for a query to succeed, and a near infinite number of ways for it to fail. Never EVER assume success, since the odds are literally 1 in infinity. Always check for failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Comment: My query is working, I tryed it on mysql workbench. Only if somehow it is not working in php. I used alert in else block if it return false, but nothing happend so i ASSUME that query is ok.

Answer (score 0):

i feel your query is not getting any resultset.
First Thing 
In orignial query group by needs to be  **group by date_earned** instead of group by dayEarned 
A better way to write the above code would be

```
<?php
      $qry = "SELECT dayname(date_earned) as dayEarned, sum(downloads) as dayDownloaded
             FROM perf_earnings
             WHERE date_earned between DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
             AND curdate()
             GROUP BY date_earned";

     $qid  = mysql_query($qry);
     if($qid->num_rows()){
       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qid)){
          $day = $row["dayEarned"];
          $dowSum = $row["dayDownloaded"];
          $days[$day] = $dowSum;

       }
     }

?>
```